# Concept of Rational Expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

I am in doubt if the following is considered a rational expression:

$$\dfrac{1}{x^{-2}}$$

From what I understand, rational expressions cannot have a negative exponent. However, is it okay to have a negative exponent in the denominator?

Also, can $x$ alone be considered a rational expression?

Comment: You can always clear negative exponents by multiplying the numerator and denominator by the reciprocal, so you don't gain anything by allowing them.

Comment: A rational function is a ratio of polynomials. Your example is $x^2/1$.

Comment: Thanks!! I get that. I just wanted to know if it’s still considered by definition a rational expression. From what I understood, it’s not considered a rational expression if there is a negative exponent on the numerator. Just not sure if that’s the case for the denominator.

Comment: So from what you are saying, since  1/x^-2 is the same as x^2/1, 1/x^-2 is a rational expression, right ?

Comment: Well as $\frac 1{x^{-2}} = x^2$ is certainly legitimate, perhaps we need to look into the spirit more than the letter of of law.

Comment: "From what I understand, rational expressions cannot have a negative exponent."  I'm not sure that I have ever heard that.  As $p(x) =x^2\implies \frac 1{p(x)} = x^{-2}$ is clearly a rational expression, I would say that simply is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *subtle*.

A **rational expression** is of the form

$$\frac{a_0+a_1x+\cdots +a_nx^n}{b_0+b_1x+\cdots +b_mx^m}.$$

You just replace the $a_i$ and $b_i$ by actual numbers, then what you obtain is a term which is considered to be a rational expression. In this form, terms like

$$1/x^{-2}\qquad\text{or}\qquad x$$

are *not* rational expressions, because they are not of the form above.

Then there is something like a **rational function**, which is a function $f(x)$ that *can* be computed by a rational expression as above. Take for example the function $f(x)=1/x^{-2}$. While $1/x^{-2}$ is not a rational expression, we can transform it (using equivalence transformations) to such one:

$$1/x^{-2} = x^2 = x^2/1.$$

So (for a second, ignoring the case $x=0$), we can also write $f(x)=x^2/1$, where the term on the right is evidently a rational expression. So the function given by $1/x^{-2}$ is a rational function, despite it was not given by a rational expression in the first place.

However, this is only one view on the topic. Usually equivalent terms like $1/x^{-2}$ and $x^2/1$ are considered as *the same* term (which is not correct formally, but makes mostly no difference in applications). Hence we say that $1/x^{-2}$ is a rational expression, despite it is only equivalent to one.